# Gitlab shows my changes only after restart

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some troubles with how gitlab CI 8.5.7 works.

I create a new repository with gitlab ui and see the start page for empty repository. After that I push some data with `git push -u prigin master` and get message that data pushed succeefully. But in gitlab I still see  empty repository. Only after restart using something like `sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab restart` my data appear in gitlab. After restarting it several days working properly. But the problem occurs again.

Also I have some bug with deploy keys. After some time I need restart gitlab to make new keys work.

Comment: Try to push your changes without the `-u` flag: `git push origin master`.

Comment: Oh, and try to upgrade to 8.6, is much better than 8.5! :)